# SQL Exclude all rows if 1 is matched for employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tried a few ways to no avail, this gives me a marker to show who has Aux

```
select 
        convert(varchar(10), [SchedDate], 103) as SchedDate
     , [HrId]
     , [Skill]
     , [MuId]
     , a.[FirstName]
     , a.[LastName]
     , a.SupervisorId
     , b.FirstName + ' ' + b.LastName         Supervisor
     , [Exception]
     , convert(varchar(8), [Start], 108)      as 'Start'
     , convert(varchar(8), [Stop], 108)       as 'Stop'
     ,case
                            when Exception like 'Aux%' then
                                1
                            else
                                0
                        end as 'Aux'
from [dbo].[IEXDataImport]         as i
    left join dbo.EmployeeHierachy as a
        on a.[EmployeeId] = i.HrId
    left join dbo.EmployeeHierachy as b
        on a.SupervisorId = b.EmployeeId
where (convert(varchar(10), SchedDate, 103) >= convert(varchar(10), dateadd(DD, datediff(DY, 0, getdate()), 0), 103))
      and i.Exception not in ( 'Aux 02 Unpaid Break', 'Aux 01 Unpaid Lunch' )
      ;
```

What I need to do is now exclude all HRid for that day who have a 1 in the column, the issue I have is the 1 will only appear on 1 record for the HRid however they may have 6 or 7 records for the day so all the records for that day need to be removed, and this is where I get stuck.

I've tried grouping but to no avail and my SQL is not good enough to fix this.

Sample of data, I have 300k rows like this

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylhKD.png)

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>SchedDate</th><th>HrId</th><th>Skill</th><th>MuId</th><th>Exception</th><th>Start</th><th>Stop</th><th>Aux</th></tr><tr><td>13/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>AUX 05</td><td>14:45:00</td><td>15:15:00</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>13/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>09:30:00</td><td>11:45:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>13/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>12:00:00</td><td>14:15:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>13/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>15:15:00</td><td>16:00:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>13/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>16:15:00</td><td>18:00:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>13/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Unpaid Break</td><td>11:45:00</td><td>12:00:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>13/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Unpaid Break</td><td>16:00:00</td><td>16:15:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>13/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Unpaid Lunch</td><td>14:15:00</td><td>14:45:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>14/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>09:30:00</td><td>12:00:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>14/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>12:15:00</td><td>14:15:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>14/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>14:45:00</td><td>16:00:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>14/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>16:15:00</td><td>18:00:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>14/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Unpaid Break</td><td>12:00:00</td><td>12:15:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>14/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Unpaid Break</td><td>16:00:00</td><td>16:15:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>14/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Unpaid Lunch</td><td>14:15:00</td><td>14:45:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>19/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>09:30:00</td><td>11:45:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>19/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>12:00:00</td><td>14:15:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>19/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>14:45:00</td><td>16:15:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>19/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Open Time</td><td>16:30:00</td><td>18:00:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>19/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Unpaid Break</td><td>11:45:00</td><td>12:00:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>19/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Unpaid Break</td><td>16:15:00</td><td>16:30:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>19/04/2021</td><td>1</td><td>Enquiries</td><td>99</td><td>Unpaid Lunch</td><td>14:15:00</td><td>14:45:00</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>This is the exmaple entities</td><td>Te&lt;br /&gt;st</td><td>45</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

And need to exclude each day where the employee has a 1 on 1 of the rows for that day

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your sample data and expected results, as formatted text in the question, not linked images. Ideally we need a [mre] with the sample data being DDL+DML i.e. consumable for working with.

Comment: hi not sure how to do that the image shows the output i am getting the 13/04/2021 should excluded as Aux has a 1 in 1 of the rows 14/04 is ok no 1 in Aux so this would need to stay

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: Yeah trying to explain data as text might make sense to you, but is very hard to communicate to others. The clearer your question is (for us) the faster you will get an answer.

Comment: well ive tried above

Comment: You can use `where not exists(select ...)` kind of clause, in inner query you check for records, having 1 on your critical column and same hrid as in main query.

Comment: What's with the `convert`s, why don't you just use `>= and <`